# How to consume wcf service in xamarin.forms?

Tags: wcf, xamarin.forms

I am new for xamrin forms, now i want to access wcf service in xamarin froms`WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";

```
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjInput);                

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
            }

            HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream reader = responce.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(reader);
            string outResult = sReader.ReadToEnd();              

            return outResult;` am using this code but getting error in Getresponse stream.
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Official xamarin walkthrough: [Walkthrough - Working with WCF](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/)

Official xamarin walkthrough to consume WFC: [Consuming a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) Web Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/wcf/)

Official xamarin sample from walkthrough: [WCF Walkthrough Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/WCF-Walkthrough/)